# How to return Id insert stored procedure + mybatis

Tags: java, sql-server, mybatis

I have a stored procedure that return an ID (sql server 2005):

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
      rolTemplateWeek(rolWeek,employee,date_insert) 
      VALUES(@numberRol,@employeeId,getDate())
   Select @id = @@IDENTITY
END
```

Mapper.xml

```
    <insert  id="saveRol" parameterType="com.service.specual.dto.RolWeek" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { call saveRolWeek(
        #{numberRol,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN},
        #{employeeId,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN},
        #{id,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=OUT}
    )}
</insert>
```

RolWeek.class

```
    public class RolWeek {

    private int id;
        private int numberRol;
    private int employeeId;
        .... get & setters
```

Mapper.java

```
   RolWeek rolWeek= new RolWeek ();
   rolWeek.setNumberRol(120);
   rolWeek.setEmployeeId(100);

   public int saveServiceRolWeek(RolWeek rolWeek);
```

Insert fine but not return my ID , only "1" ¿how I could return my inserted ID?

Answer (score 1):

```
--
-- Use output clause, make sure id is OUTPUT
--

CREATE PROCEDURE saveRolWeek
   @numberRol INT,
   @employeeId INT,
   @id INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @id =
      INSERT INTO rolTemplateWeek(rolWeek, employee, date_insert) 
      OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
      VALUES(@numberRol, @employeeId, getDate());
END

-- Sample call with 1, 1 as parameters
DECLARE @retid int = null;
EXECUTE dbo.saveRolWeek 1, 1, @retid = @id OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Thanks, yes my Id is output. When I tried modify my stored procedure with your coude show me error with the insert: "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID" this statement must be in the middle?